# Error on line 40, column 4 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping. assets: ^

Tags: image, flutter, assert

## To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

assets:
    - images/contact.png
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

Comment: can you post the section where you are adding your `assets` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error

my problem was that `uses-material-design:` and `assets:` were misaligned

```
   uses-material-design: true  //column 3 

    # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
    assets://column 4
```

The simple solution was to make sure that my assets section was aligned with my use materials design section, in other words they should be put together in the same column as the following code:

```
   uses-material-design: true  //column 3

    # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
   assets://column 3
```

Comment: Would have been great if they used JSON, YAML is annoying to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Include all assets in assets folder located in the application directory

my pubspec file looks like

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
```

use it like

```
Image.asset('assets/logo.png')
```

**make sure to indented properly to avoid error.**

Answer (score 0):

just set the indentation 
name: flutter_demo1
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
   sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
   sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/